# Laravel 5: Dynamically Generate Links (Routes) to Uploaded Files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have a simple form where users can upload files. Files are uploaded to *public/uploads* directory.

Below the form there is a list of all the files in *public/uploads* directory.

So, here is my controller method:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('file_upload')) {
        if ($request->file('file_upload')->isValid()) {
            $request->file('file_upload')->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $request->file('file_upload')->getClientOriginalName());
        }
    }

    $list_of_files = \File::allFiles(public_path().'/uploads/');

    return view('foo', compact('list_of_files'));
}
```

and here is the View file that displays the list of files:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($list_of_files as $file)
        <li><a href="#">{{ basename($file) }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

What should I put in **href=" "** to have links to those files (and what routes do I need to have so these links work)?

Comment: not the solution or what you are looking for  but use this to name the files and avoid other future trouble  date('Y-m-d-H:i:s')."-".$image->getClientOriginalName();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `asset()` helper to generate a URL to your public directory.

Given you are storing your files in your `uploads` directory. You would use it like so  `<li><a href="{{ asset('uploads/' . basename($file)) }}">{{ basename($file) }}</a></li>`

You just need to make sure the `basename($file)` is the name the file so that when they click on the link it actually takes them to the file.

In full:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($list_of_files as $file)
        <li><a href="{{ asset('uploads/' . basename($file)) }}">{{ basename($file) }}</a></li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have just one more _noob_ question about routes: now that I have links to files, when I click on some link (for example to open some .pdf document) I will have the following URL: http://localhost/uploads/invoice_sale.pdf. I don't have anything defined in **routes.php** that matches such URLs (**uploads/some_file_name**). I thought that if we want such links to work - we need to define them in routes.php? I mean, every URL on my website have to be defined in routes.php in order to work, right? Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: If the directory is inside your public folder then you navigate to it yourself directly - the same way you can with css files or JavaScript files. If the directory is outside of your public folder then you will need to set up a route and function to handle the viewing or downloading of the file

Comment: @PeraMika for example if you had the file invoice.pdf stored at public/uploads/invoice.pdf then you could navigate to that directly in Your browser using example.com/uploads/invoice.pdf without having to define a specific route for it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

```
href="/public/{{ basename($file) }}"
```

Should do the job to make the links to work without restrictions